# NodeJS Bulk Insert MySQL Using Sequelize with Chunk Data

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, nestjs, bulkinsert

I want to bulk insert MySQL with Sequelize ORM and NodeJS (NestJS). I'm curious if there is a best way to handle very large data. I thought of "chunk" like Laravel did. In Laravel we can do it like this:

```
$chunks = $insert_data->chunk(500);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
   \DB::table('items_details')->insert($chunk->toArray());
}
```

Has anyone implemented this with sequelize and NodeJS. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it would be almost the same (using `lodash` to get chunks):

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

const chunks = _.chunk(insert_data, 500);

for (const chunk of chunks) {
  await ItemDetails.bulkCreate(chunk);
}
```

P.S. Depending on what you want to achieve you either use a transaction to insert all chunks or none of them if there will is an error while inserting any of chunks OR use `try/catch` to bypass or continue inserting other chunks after failed one.